# How to connect to gitHub api using nodejs from a secure network?

Tags: node.js

I am using the below code to get the repositories from gitHub. When I use it from Home network I am able to retrieve the list of repositories, but If I try to fetch the repo from other network it gives me this error: 'connect ECONNREFUSED'. I am new to nodejs, so still wondering how to go about solving this issue.

Any ideas?

```
var https = require("https");
var userName='xyz';
var options = {
host :"api.github.com",
path : '/users/'+userName+'/repos',
method : 'GET'
}

var request = https.request(options, function(response){
var body = '';
response.on('data',function(chunk){
    body+=chunk;
});
response.on('end',function(){
    var json = JSON.parse(body);
    var repos =[];
    json.forEach(function(repo){
        repos.push({
            name : repo.name,
            description : repo.description
        });
    });
    console.log('the repos are  '+ JSON.stringify(repos));
});

});
request.on('error', function(e) {
console.error('and the error is '+e);
});
request.end();
```

Comment: can you include more details about the error? about the version of node used, the OS?  Above code appears to work fine so error would be due to environment.

Comment: It normally happens when you try to run it behind proxy that causes this kind of errors.

Comment: Yeah I a running it behind a proxy. How do I configure or override it to run run the above code??

Comment: I know its not appropriate to ask here but can you tell me how you are passing that path. I been trying this all day long

Answer (score 3):

Change your options as

```
var options = {

host:'api.github.com',

path: '/users/' + username+ '/repos',

method: 'GET',

headers: {'user-agent':'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)'}

};
```

Answer (score 3):

i think this would be OK

```
var options = {

host:'api.github.com',

path: '/users/' + username+ '/repos',

method: 'GET',

headers: {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)'}

};
```